# Running a scrapy spider in the background in a Flask app

Tags: python, flask, scrapy, python-multithreading

I'm building an app that uses [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) and [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/). When the root URL of my app is accessed, it processes some data and displays it. In addition, I also want to (re)start my spider if it is not already running. Since my spider takes about 1.5 hrs to finish running, I run it as a background process using [threading](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/threading.html). Here is a minimal example (you'll also need [testspiders](https://github.com/scrapinghub/testspiders)):

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template
import threading
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy import log, signals
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy.settings import Settings    
from testspiders.spiders.followall import FollowAllSpider

def crawl():
    spider = FollowAllSpider(domain='scrapinghub.com')
    crawler = Crawler(Settings())
    crawler.configure()
    crawler.signals.connect(reactor.stop, signal=signals.spider_closed)
    crawler.crawl(spider)
    crawler.start()
    log.start()
    reactor.run()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def main():
    run_in_bg = threading.Thread(target=crawl, name='crawler')
    thread_names = [t.name for t in threading.enumerate() if isinstance(t, threading.Thread)]

    if 'crawler' not in thread_names:
        run_in_bg.start()

    return 'hello world'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

As a side note, the following lines were my ad hoc approach to try and identify if my crawler thread is still running. If there's a more idiomatic approach, I'd appreciate some guidance.

```
run_in_bg = threading.Thread(target=crawl, name='crawler')
thread_names = [t.name for t in threading.enumerate() if isinstance(t, threading.Thread)]

if 'crawler' not in thread_names:
    run_in_bg.start()
```

Moving on to the problem — if I save the above script as `crawler.py`, run `python crawler.py` and access `localhost:5000`, then I get the following error (ignore scrapy's `HtmlXPathSelector` deprecation errors):

```
exceptions.ValueError: signal only works in main thread
```

Although the spider runs, it doesn't stop because the `signals.spider_closed` signal only works in the main thread (according to this error). As expected, subsequent requests to the root URL results in copious errors.

How can I design my app to start my spider if it is not already crawling, while at the same time returning control back to my app immediately (i.e. I don't want to wait for the crawler to finish) for other stuff?

Comment: I added answer in similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36384286/how-to-integrate-flask-scrapy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its not the best idea to have flask start long running threads like this.

I would recommend using a queue system like celery or rabbitmq. Your flask application can put tasks on the queue that you would like to do in the background and then return immediately.

Then you can have workers outside of your main app process those tasks and do all of your scraping.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about Celery. I implemented it, and while it seems to work (and looks nicer/cleaner than my threading solution), I still have the same problem with the reactor not being able to restart or send the stop signal. I'll try fiddling with it some more, and will accept if I can get it to work.