# How to pass parameters to scrapy spiders in program?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am a newbie of python and scrapy. I used the method in this blog [Running multiple scrapy spiders programmatically](http://kirankoduru.github.io/python/multiple-scrapy-spiders.html) to run my spiders in a flask app.Here is the code:

```
# list of crawlers
TO_CRAWL = [DmozSpider, EPGDspider, GDSpider]

# crawlers that are running 
RUNNING_CRAWLERS = []

def spider_closing(spider):
    """
    Activates on spider closed signal
    """
    log.msg("Spider closed: %s" % spider, level=log.INFO)
    RUNNING_CRAWLERS.remove(spider)
    if not RUNNING_CRAWLERS:
        reactor.stop()

# start logger
log.start(loglevel=log.DEBUG)

# set up the crawler and start to crawl one spider at a time
for spider in TO_CRAWL:
    settings = Settings()

    # crawl responsibly
    settings.set("USER_AGENT", "Kiran Koduru (+http://kirankoduru.github.io)")
    crawler = Crawler(settings)
    crawler_obj = spider()
    RUNNING_CRAWLERS.append(crawler_obj)

    # stop reactor when spider closes
    crawler.signals.connect(spider_closing, signal=signals.spider_closed)
    crawler.configure()
    crawler.crawl(crawler_obj)
    crawler.start()

# blocks process; so always keep as the last statement
reactor.run()
```

Here is my spiders code:

```
class EPGDspider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "EPGD"
allowed_domains = ["epgd.biosino.org"]
term = "man"
start_urls = ["http://epgd.biosino.org/EPGD/search/textsearch.jsp?textquery="+term+"&submit=Feeling+Lucky"]
MONGODB_DB = name + "_" + term
MONGODB_COLLECTION = name + "_" + term

def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    sites = sel.xpath('//tr[@class="odd"]|//tr[@class="even"]')
    url_list = []
    base_url = "http://epgd.biosino.org/EPGD"

    for site in sites:
        item = EPGD()
        item['genID'] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[1]/a/text()').extract())
        item['genID_url'] = base_url+map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[1]/a/@href').extract())[0][2:]
        item['taxID'] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[2]/a/text()').extract())
        item['taxID_url'] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[2]/a/@href').extract())
        item['familyID'] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[3]/a/text()').extract())
        item['familyID_url'] = base_url+map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[3]/a/@href').extract())[0][2:]
        item['chromosome'] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[4]/text()').extract())
        item['symbol'] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[5]/text()').extract())
        item['description'] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[6]/text()').extract())
        yield item

    sel_tmp = Selector(response)
    link = sel_tmp.xpath('//span[@id="quickPage"]')

    for site in link:
        url_list.append(site.xpath('a/@href').extract())

    for i in range(len(url_list[0])):
        if cmp(url_list[0][i], "#") == 0:
            if i+1 < len(url_list[0]):
                print url_list[0][i+1]
                actual_url = "http://epgd.biosino.org/EPGD/search/"+ url_list[0][i+1]
                yield Request(actual_url, callback=self.parse)
                break
            else:
                print "The index is out of range!"
```

As you can see, there is a parameter `term = 'man'` in my code, and it's part of my `start urls`. I don't want this parameter to be fixed, so I wonder how can I give the `start url` or the parameter `term` dynamically in my program? Just like running a spider in command line there is a way can pass parameter as below:

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):

    name = 'my_spider'    

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
      super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 

      self.start_urls = [kwargs.get('start_url')] 
And start it like: scrapy crawl my_spider -a start_url="http://some_url"
```

Can anybody tell me how to deal with this?

Comment: Yes `scrapy crawl my_spider -a start_url="http://google.com"`  works fine

Comment: But I don't want to call my spiders in command line, I want to call spiders in my program.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, to run multiple spiders in a script, the recommended way is to use [`scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess), [where you pass spider classes](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html?#run-scrapy-from-a-script) and not spider instances.

To pass arguments to your spider with `CrawlerProcess`, you just have to add the arguments to the `.crawl()` call, after the spider subclass,
e.g.

```
    process.crawl(DmozSpider, term='someterm', someotherterm='anotherterm')
```

Arguments passed this way are then available as spider attributes (same as with `-a term=someterm` on the command line)

Finally, instead of building `start_urls` in `__init__`, you can achieve the same with [`start_requests`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=start_requests#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests), and you can build initial requests like this, using `self.term`:

```
def start_requests(self):
    yield Request("http://epgd.biosino.org/"
                  "EPGD/search/textsearch.jsp?"
                  "textquery={}"
                  "&submit=Feeling+Lucky".format(self.term))
```

Comment: First,thank you for your detailed answer!! I've tried `CrawlerProcess`,but there is a problem that I can't use this in Flask App, when I use that there is a bug said that signal only works in main thread,and I have ask this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36384286/cant-call-scrapy-spiders-in-flask-web-framework),but there is no effective solutions.So do you have other method?

Comment: If you want to use `scrapy.crawler.Crawler`, [it needs to be instantiated with `(spidercls, settings)`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#scrapy.crawler.Crawler), not only settings. e.g. `crawler = Crawler(DmozSpider, settings)` and then `crawler.crawl(term="someterm")`

Comment: The problem is that I run these spiders in a Flask App, so I should try `scrapy.crawler.Crawler` instead of `CrawlerProcess`?

Comment: I don't know how to run scrapy spider in a Flask app. I'll ask around

Comment: I found that I use `scrapy - 0.24.0` instead of `scrapy -1.0`, and in `scrapy - 0.24.0`,the Crawler only has one parameter `settings`, it's a little different from the latest one.

Comment: Ok, then check 0.24 docs, there's [an example with a spider being passed arguments](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.24/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script):

Comment: Sorry, I have read this official document,but I don't see there is an example passing arguments...I have also tried the `scrapy  -1.0` method `Crawler Runner`, does the method `Crawler Runner` has a way to pass argument?

Comment: Thanks @paultrmbrth for the feedback. I will update my blog post as you suggested.