# Get Scrapy crawler output/results in script file function

Tags: python, web-crawler, twisted, scrapy

I am using a script file to run a spider within scrapy project and spider is logging the crawler output/results. But i want to use spider output/results in that script file in some function .I did not want to save output/results in any file or DB.
Here is Script code get from https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-from-script

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

configure_logging({'LOG_FORMAT': '%(levelname)s: %(message)s'})
runner = CrawlerRunner(get_project_settings())


d = runner.crawl('my_spider')
d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
reactor.run()

def spider_output(output):
#     do something to that output
```

How can i get spider output in 'spider_output' method. It is possible to get output/results.

Answer (score 30):

Here is the solution that get all output/results in a list

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

from scrapy.signalmanager import dispatcher


def spider_results():
    results = []

    def crawler_results(signal, sender, item, response, spider):
        results.append(item)

    dispatcher.connect(crawler_results, signal=signals.item_scraped)

    process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
    process.crawl(MySpider)
    process.start()  # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
    return results


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(spider_results())
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, do you have a pipeline working or anything?

Comment: It's works to me,, just note `MySpider` is your spider class.. it's very helpful for beginner..

Comment: FYI as of Scrapy 0.14 `item_passed` was renamed to `item_scraped`.  
Source :https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/news.html  
older `item_passed` docs: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/0.9/topics/signals.html#item-passed  
new `item_scaped` docs: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#item-scraped

Answer (score 8):

This is an old question, but for future reference. If you are working with python 3.6+ I recommend using [scrapyscript](https://github.com/jschnurr/scrapyscript) that allows you to run your Spiders and get the results in a super simple way:

```py
from scrapyscript import Job, Processor
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy import Request
import json

# Define a Scrapy Spider, which can accept *args or **kwargs
# https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#spider-arguments
class PythonSpider(Spider):
    name = 'myspider'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request(self.url)

    def parse(self, response):
        title = response.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
        return {'url': response.request.url, 'title': title}

# Create jobs for each instance. *args and **kwargs supplied here will
# be passed to the spider constructor at runtime
githubJob = Job(PythonSpider, url='http://www.github.com')
pythonJob = Job(PythonSpider, url='http://www.python.org')

# Create a Processor, optionally passing in a Scrapy Settings object.
processor = Processor(settings=None)

# Start the reactor, and block until all spiders complete.
data = processor.run([githubJob, pythonJob])

# Print the consolidated results
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

```
[
    {
        "title": [
            "Welcome to Python.org"
        ],
        "url": "https://www.python.org/"
    },
    {
        "title": [
            "The world's leading software development platform \u00b7 GitHub",
            "1clr-code-hosting"
        ],
        "url": "https://github.com/"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no way to do this, since [crawl()](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#scrapy.crawler.CrawlerRunner.crawl):

> Returns a deferred that is fired when the crawling is finished.

And the crawler doesn't store results anywhere other than outputting them to logger.

However returning ouput would conflict with the whole asynchronious nature and structure of scrapy, so saving to file then reading it is a prefered approach here.
You can simply devise pipeline that saves your items to file and simply read the file in your `spider_output`. You will receive your results since `reactor.run()` is blocking your script untill the output file is complete anyways.

Comment: Yes you are right crawler doesn't store results but using signals we can get results

Comment: @SheikhJames Oh right, forgot about signals completely. That's very clever!

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to use the Python `subprocess` module to run spider from the script rather than using the method provided in the scrapy docs to run spider from python script. The reason for that is that with the `subprocess` module, you can capture the output/logs and even statements that you `print` from inside the spider.

In Python 3, execute the spider with the `run` method. Ex.

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
if process.returncode == 0:
    result = process.stdout.decode('utf-8')
else:
    # code to check error using 'process.stderr'
```

Setting the stdout/stderr to `subprocess.PIPE` will allow capture of output so it's very important to set this flag.
Here `command` should be a sequence or a string (It it's a string, then call the `run` method with 1 more param: `shell=True`). For example:

```
command = ['scrapy', 'crawl', 'website', '-a', 'customArg=blahblah']
# or
command = 'scrapy crawl website -a customArg=blahblah' # with shell=True
#or
import shlex
command = shlex.split('scrapy crawl website -a customArg=blahblah') # without shell=True
```

Also, `process.stdout` will contain the output from the script but it will be of type `bytes`. You need to convert it to `str` using `decode('utf-8')`

Answer (score 0):

It's going to return all the results of a Spider within a list.

```
from scrapyscript import Job, Processor
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings


def get_spider_output(spider, **kwargs):
    job = Job(spider, **kwargs)
    processor = Processor(settings=get_project_settings())
    return processor.run([job])
```