# retrieve scraped items from scrapy crawl when triggered via CrawlerRunner

Tags: python, scrapy

I have 2 spiders in a scrapy project. They work just fine and produce the required output items.

I want to execute these spiders in a background job in a web application.

Everything is setup - a Flask app with a background job setup using Redis - frontend waits for results - all is well.

Except i can't seem to work out how to get the resulting items from the spiders when they execute.

The closest i've come seems to be the answer to this question

[Get Scrapy crawler output/results in script file function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40237952/get-scrapy-crawler-output-results-in-script-file-function)

but it seems to refer to an older version of scrapy (i'm using 1.4.0) and i get the deprecation warning

'ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Importing from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch is deprecated and will no longer be supported in future Scrapy versions. If you just want to connect signals use the from_crawler class method, otherwise import pydispatch directly if needed. See: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1762'

checking that github issue suggests this wouldn't have worked from around v1.1.0

So, can anyone tell me how to do this now?

Comment: In the GitHub issue referred, there's shown how to use the `from_crawler` method to connect signals in new versions of Scrapy.

Comment: yes, that's right, but i'm calling the `CrawlerRunner` from within the background job. If i place the example `@classmethod` there it's not going to get called by the scrapy framework.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out it's pretty easy - must have been too late at night for me.

replace

`from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher`

with

`from pydispatch import dispatcher`

as it clearly says in the deprecation warning

`otherwise import pydispatch directly if needed.`