# How do I fix scrapy Unsupported URL scheme error?

Tags: python, flask, scrapy

I collect url from command python and then insert it into start_urls

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import scrapy
import subprocess

class ClassSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name        = 'mySpider'
    #start_urls = []
    #pages      = 0
    news        = []

    def __init__(self, url, nbrPage):
        self.pages      = nbrPage
        self.start_urls = []
        self.start_urlsappend(url)

    def parse(self):
        ...

    def run(self):
        subprocess.check_output(['scrapy', 'crawl', 'mySpider', '-a', f'url={self.start_urls}', '-a', f'nbrPage={self.pages}'])
        return self.news

app = Flask(__name__)
data = []

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def getNews():
    mySpiderClass = ClassSpider(request.json['url'], 2)
    return jsonify({'data': mySpider.run()})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I got this error: raise not supported("unsupported url scheme %s: %s" %
scrapy.exceptions.NotSupported: Unsupported URL scheme '': no handler available for that scheme

When I put a 
`print('my urls List: ' + str(self.start_urls))`, it prints a list of url like --> my urls List: ['www.googole.com']

Any help plz

Comment: Maybe you need `http://` or `https://` in front of your URLs?

Comment: I have a https.
I don't have any issues when I put directly the url at `self.start_urls = ['https://theURL']`
WHY :(

Comment: I don't know anything about `scrapy` but maybe it supports lots of different protocols like `ftp://`.  It won't know which to use unless you're explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this happens because you first append `url` to `self.start_urls` and then you call `ClassSpider`s `run` method with your list `self.start_urls` which in turn appends the list to a list and you end up with a nested list instead of a list of strings.
To avoid this you should maybe change your `__init__` method like this:

```py
    def __init__(self, url, nbrPage):
        self.pages      = nbrPage
        self.url        = url
        self.start_urls = []
        self.start_urls.append(url)
```

And then pass `self.url` instead of `self.start_urls` in `run`:

```py
    def run(self):
        subprocess.check_output(['scrapy', 'crawl', 'mySpider', '-a', f'url={self.url}', '-a', f'nbrPage={self.pages}'])
        return self.news
```

Comment: You are a genious, thank you very much. I'm noob at python and scrapy knots my brain.

Comment: Thank you, but no, I'm not ;) I only already made all of these mistakes. Glad to help!