# Python Scrapy -> Use a scrapy spider as a function

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

so I have the following Scrapy Spider in `spiders.py`

```py
import scrapy 

class TwitchSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = "clips"

  def start_requests(self):
      urls = [
          f'https://www.twitch.tv/wilbursoot/clips?filter=clips&range=7d'
      ]

  def parse(self, response): 
    for clip in response.css('.tw-tower'):
      yield {
        'title': clip.css('::text').get()
      }
```

But the key aspect is that I want to call this spider as a function, in another file, instead of using `scrapy crawl quotes` in the console. Where can I read more on this, or whether this is possible at all? I checked through the Scrapy documentation, but I didn't find much

Comment: This question was answered before numerous times (eg: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31374345), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34987612) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62248517)) and there's an example in the documentation. I answered your question, but next time do a little more research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the spider from main.py:

```py
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spider = 'TwitchSpider'
    settings = get_project_settings()
    # change/update settings:
    settings['USER_AGENT'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'
    process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
    process.crawl(spider)
    process.start()
```

[Run scrapy from a script](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script).

Comment: so like I dont need to import the spider itself in any way to main.py, just as long as I reference the name of it, scrapy will parse all the files for a spider?

Comment: As long you create a project then no, you don't need to import it. You can even run multiple spiders from main.py

Answer (score 0):

Put your other file in the same directory as your spider file. Then import the spider file like

```
import spider
```

Then you will have access to the spider file and can make a spider object.

```
spi = spider()
```

Then can call functions on that object such as

```
spi.parse()
```

This article shows you how to import other python files classes and functions https://csatlas.com/python-import-file-module/

Comment: It won't work. Not in scrapy.